# Two XAML pages with same code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I'm creating an Windows Universal App (WinRT and WP8.1).
What I want is to have an user choose between two different layouts for the same page. 
Below is a *simple representation*.
I'd like to find the simplest, laziest approach (I know I could just create two pages, but there must be a better way.)
I have already created 1 page (500 lines of C# code behind to handle control interactions) and now need to add the second layout to it. The two layouts have the exact same functions and the controls have the same names, they are just arranged differently.

**In Android I could do:**

```
if(IsLayout1Selected)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_d2p_layout1);

else
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_d2p_layout2);
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Layout1:**

```
<Page x:Name="d2pPageLayout1"
x:Class="_MyApp.D2P"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:_MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Unloaded="PageUnloaded" Loaded="PageLoaded"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Button x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="buttonClick"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textblock1" Text="Hello"/>
        <!-- Of course there are a lot more elements and they have many layout properties that differ -->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Layout2:**

```
<Page x:Name="d2pPageLayout2"
x:Class="_MyApp.D2P"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:_MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Unloaded="PageUnloaded" Loaded="PageLoaded"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Button x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="buttonClick"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textblock1" Text="Hello"/>
        <!-- Of course there are a lot more elements and they have many layout properties that differ -->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code behind (same for Layout 1 and Layout 2):**

```
namespace _MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class D2P : Page
    {
    public D2P()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // do stuff here
        }

    private void PageUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // do some other stuff here
        }

    private void buttonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // handle buttonClick here
            // a lot of this code also references the controls directly e.g.
            textblock1.Text = "Button 1 was clicked";
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the tip from Akshay Soam I came pretty close to what I wanted by using DataTemplate and ContentControl, but now this results in another problem, breaking my code. My code accesses a lot of elements directly.
Example:

```
textblock1.Text = "Button 1 was clicked";
```

Since my entire page content is now wrapped inside the DataTemplate I cannot access the elements anymore. How do I do this?

Current implementation is:

**XAML:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template1">
        <Button x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="buttonClick"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textblock1" Text="Hello"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

**Code behind:**

```
contentControl.ContentTemplate = template1;
this.DataContext = template1;
```

Comment: you could use a contentcontrol in combination with a datatemplate

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Thanks, that got me halfway there, I have updated the question with a resulting problem.

Answer (score 1):

As for your new problem, you can either browse the VisualTree and extract it out.

Here is one of my old answer on the topic: [VisualTree Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049841/obtain-datagrid-inside-itemscontrol-from-the-binded-item/26051196#26051196)

---

But don't do it like that.  You want to use a MVVM pattern and Bind the .Text to a property of a ModelView and that Button to a Command of that ModelView.  That way you can change the property and through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` --- changing the .Text property it will automatically update the TextBox with the new changes.

---

A very easy to read MVVM article I wrote answering related SO question.  It has the Button Command as well.  Unfortunately, this isn't `WinForms` so you have to play by the rules.

[Implement a ViewModel Single Command with CommandParamater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613212/how-to-implement-a-navigation-button-in-shared-application-resources/25627927#25627927)

Comment: Thanks. In the future, I will be sure to start out with a MVVM pattern. However for this almost finished application, I rely on a number of functions that depend on a control being passed to it (mainly animation stuff). Shifting everything to MVVM would take ages. I had hoped I could somehow change the `this.InitializeComponent();` call to initialize based on another XAML page as I can in Android with `setContentView`. I'm currently trying to get the VisualTreeHelper to work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could share the same layout(`XAML`) code within your `Universal` app such as using the same `GUI` for both `Win` and `WP`. But you won't be able to share the same UI code for the pages within `Win` or `WP`.

[Tips and tricks for using XAML controls in your universal Windows apps](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/07/22/tips-and-tricks-for-using-xaml-controls-in-your-universal-windows-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

You can Build more than one xaml for the same page like here:
I built 8 xaml for the same MainPage for different screen size

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{


    public MainPage()
    {

        Rect bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
        double scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
        Size size = new Size(bounds.Width * scaleFactor, bounds.Height * scaleFactor);



        string resourceName;

        if (size.Width >= 1920 && size.Height >= 1080) resourceName = "ms-appx:///MainPage.layout-1920x1080.xaml";
        else if (size.Width >= 1680 && size.Height >= 1050) resourceName = "ms-appx:///MainPage.layout-1680x1050.xaml";
        else if (size.Width >= 1600 && size.Height >= 1200) resourceName = "ms-appx:///MainPage.layout-1600x1200.xaml";
        else if (size.Width >= 1360 && size.Height >= 768) resourceName = "ms-appx:///MainPage.layout-1360x768.xaml";
        else if (size.Width >= 1280 && size.Height >= 1024) resourceName = "ms-appx:///MainPage.layout-1280x1024.xaml";
        else if (size.Width >= 1024 && size.Height >= 768) resourceName = "ms-appx:///MainPage.layout-1024x768.xaml";
        else if (size.Width >= 720 && size.Height >= 480) resourceName = "ms-appx:///MainPage.layout-720x480.xaml";
        else resourceName = "ms-appx:///MainPage.layout-640x480.xaml";

        this.InitializeComponent(new Uri(resourceName, UriKind.Absolute));

    }



}
```

}

These are the links for the code that you can use it for your scenario
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/digitalsign

https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/DigitalSign