# Acces ListView.seelctionMode in c# using Hub App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Created a Hub App in WP8.1, I have a ListView that i need to modify the selection mode when the appbar button is pressed.  I cannot access the x:Name given to the listview in the .cs code behind. I have had this working on a normal page, just not working in the Hub App.

I cant access the   x:Name="WeatherListView" in the c# to change the selectionmode

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <!--TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">
        <Hub x:Name="AHubView" x:Uid="Hub" Header="A View" SectionsInViewChanged="AHubVieww_SectionsInViewChanged" >
            <!--Background="{ThemeResource HubBackgroundImageBrush}"-->
            <HubSection Name="WeatherHub" x:Uid="WeatherHub" Header="Weather Hub" DataContext="{Binding HubData}"  
                        d:DataContext="{Binding}"
                        >
                <DataTemplate  >
                    <ListView

                        x:Name="WeatherListView"
                        SelectionMode="Multiple"
                        ItemClick="WeatherListView_OnItemClick"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding DataVal}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
```

private void WeatherRemoveAppBarButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        SetDefaultWeatherButton(false);
        SetWeatherDeleteButton(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't access `<Controls>` like that if it is part of a `<DataTemplate>`, you need to browse the `VisualTree` and extract it out or **Databind the SelectionMode to a property** in your ViewModel.  And changing this Property should change the SelectionMode if done correctly.

---

[VisualTree Exaction Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049841/obtain-datagrid-inside-itemscontrol-from-the-binded-item/26051196#26051196), I recommend using the Databinding Method however.